# Delegate with real time Example

Tags: ios, class, object, delegates

Let's say we have two objects, Brain and Beer Bottle, Brain is the object we use to manage the entire Body application, it handles all of the important tasks such as poop, eat, drink, sleep etc. Beer Bottle is attached to body but it doesn't know what Brain is thinking, likewise, Brain has no idea what Beer Bottle is thinking.

Brain is using Beer Bottle's attributes to satisfy itself while it's watching TV, but the problem is that brain is so distracted by the tv that it can't pay attention to when beer is going to run out. This could all end in disaster, Brain needs to know when beer is empty so that it send body to the fridge and initialize another instance of Beer Bottle.

Brain can use the drink function to lower Beer Bottles liquid variable, but once liquid reaches 0, Brain needs to know about it, this is where delegates come into action, we can use a Beer Bottle Delegate. Brain can listen out for the Beer Bottle Delegate telling brain that the bottle is empty, all we need to do is simply tell Brain to listen out for Beer Bottle telling it's delegate that is empty and Brain can react to it.

[This well thought out and illustrated diagram shows all of this in action:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaDU5.jpg)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 

[super viewDidLoad];

UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
      initWithTitle:@"Delegate Example"
      delegate:self // telling this class to implement UIActionSheetDelegate
      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
      destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destructive Button"
      otherButtonTitles:@"Other Button",nil

[actionSheet showInView:self.view];

[actionSheet release];
}


- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
 NSLog(@"hello world!");
}

.h file:
@interface DelegateExampleViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>
{

}
```

Please show me the image flow for this code as shown in the beer bottle delegate example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help? Sorry for my handwriting.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA70p.jpg

Comment: I didn't understand this line.What this means?                                                        delegate:self // telling this class to implement UIActionSheetDelegate.